# EXCEL: Can I reference text within a cell, for a file path, in a function?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, office365

I have the following VBA module in Excel which allows me to do check if a file exists in a given folder:

```
Function FileExists(FilePath As String) As Boolean

'Declare variables
    Dim FileName As String

'Use the Dir function to get the file name
    FileName = Dir(FilePath)

'If file exists, return True else False
    If FileName <> "" Then FileExists = True _
    Else: FileExists = False

End Function
```

my result is this function which outputs `TRUE` or `FALSE` into a cell:

```
=FileExists("C:\folder\report.pdf")
```

I have one column with a list of names that want to reference in that file path so the outcome is:

```
=FileExists("C:\folder\name\report.pdf")
```

Is there a way I can do this?
I have tried using the `INDIRECT` & `T` functions but I cannot get the functions to escape and be read properly to output the name in the file path.

Comment: Do you mean something like "C:\folder\" & B1 & "\report.pdf", where column B contains the names?

Comment: Yes, but if I do that the result always returns false with any value. Even if I do `=T(B1)`.

Comment: Your problem has most probably **nothing** to do that VBA function, there seems to be an issue with the text & filename concatenation. Solve that first. Make sure a formula like `= "C:\folder\" & B1 & "\report.pdf"` without any other function produces the correct results. Then, when you created your formula correctly, paste that into your function's arguments. Solve one issue after another.

Comment: `"C:\folder" & B1 & "\report.pdf"` does output correctly when written plain into a cell: `"C:\folder\name\report.pdf"`. But when added as an argument inside this partifcular function always returns false still. I tried the same argument in `=T("C:\folder" & B1 & "\report.pdf")` and it output `"C:\folder\name\report.pdf"` correctly.

Comment: CORRECTION: `..." & B1 & "...` was the correct answer and does work, I simply had the file path pointed at a network drive that wasn't connected. So that did solve my problem!